# Truth functional completness for quantifiers

Tags: logic

There is a definition for truth-functional completness for a set of propositional connectives. Is there a definition for truth-functional completness of a set of quantifiers and propositional connectives ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There cannot be a direct analogue, because a formula with quantifiers in it can depend on the truth values of *infinitely many* atomic propositions. There are $2^{2^{\kappa}}$ different possible truth functions of $\kappa$ inputs, and when $\kappa$ is infinite this much larger than the number of possible formulas one can build from any finite set of connectives. So in this sense there is *no* complete finite set of quantifiers and connectives.

I suppose one could consider complete sets containing (uncountably) infinitely many different quantifiers, but that's not very practical.